# PyQt5 не создаётся меню

Tags: python, pyqt5

Здравствуйте, разбираюсь с PyQt5, у меня отчего-то упорно не создаётся меню...

хотя аналогичный, на мой взгляд, тулбар создаётся, подскажите нубу в чём подвох!)

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QTextEdit, QAction, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
class Example(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):               
        exitAction = QAction(QIcon('exit.png'), 'Exit', self)
        exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exitAction.setStatusTip('Exit application')
        exitAction.triggered.connect(self.close)

        self.statusBar()

        # ! тут ничего не происходит
        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(exitAction)

        # ! а тут работает
        toolbar = self.addToolBar('Exit')
        toolbar.addAction(exitAction)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 350, 250)
        self.setWindowTitle('Main window')    
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[setNativeMenuBar](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenubar.html#nativeMenuBar-prop)

как пример:

```
import random, string
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore

class MainWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    '''центральный виджет'''
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout()
        self.text = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser()
        layout.addWidget(self.text)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def cmd(self): [self.text.append(str(a)) for a in range(20)]


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.central = MainWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central)

        self.menu_bar()
        self.tool_bar()
        self.status_bar()

        self.show()

    def menu_bar(self):
        self.menuBar().setNativeMenuBar(False)
        exit_menu = self.menuBar().addMenu('&Exit')

        exit_ = QtWidgets.QAction('&Exit', self)
        exit_.setShortcut(self.tr("Ctrl+Q"))
        exit_.setStatusTip(self.tr("Exit the application"))
        exit_.triggered.connect(self.close)

        exit_menu.addAction(exit_)

    def tool_bar(self):
        toolbar = QtWidgets.QToolBar(self)
        self.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.BottomToolBarArea, toolbar)

        action = QtWidgets.QAction('Toolbar text', toolbar)
        action.triggered.connect(self.central.cmd)

        toolbar.addAction(action)

    def status_bar(self):
        sb = QtWidgets.QStatusBar()
        self.setStatusBar(sb)

        ed = QtWidgets.QPushButton('StatusBar text')
        self.statusBar().addPermanentWidget(ed)

        ed.clicked.connect(lambda: self.statusBar().showMessage(random.choice(string.ascii_letters)))

q = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
m = MainWindow()
q.exec_()
```

Comment: меню не отображается, остальные элементы вроде на месте.

[скрин](http://s8.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2016/09/912b145940415ff84ae25dc0efe21885.jpg)

Comment: попробуйте добавить self.menuBar().setNativeMenuBar(False)

Comment: это сработало, спасибо, а не могли бы вы объяснить в чём была проблема и как эта строчка её решает?

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenubar.html#nativeMenuBar-prop

Answer (score 1):

У Вас все правильно. Просто программа не находит файл exit.png.
Я просто бросил файл в рабочий каталог и все заработало.